# "Not defined" error when JS library loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with a library called browser-solc (https://github.com/ericxtang/browser-solc). When I try to load it dynamically, it says "ReferenceError: BrowserSolc is not defined". While dynamic loading of other libraries (e.g. jQuery) works. Browser-solc actually also works if not loaded dynamically...

```js
    function loadScript(url, callback)
  {
     var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.src = url;
     script.async = false;
     script.onreadystatechange = callback;
     script.onload = callback;
     head.appendChild(script);
  }

  var myPrettyCode = function() {
      console.log(BrowserSolc)
  };

  loadScript("http://code.dappbench.com/browser-solc.min.js", myPrettyCode);
```

```html
<h1>Load JS</h1>
```

Is it a problem of the particular library?

**UPDATE**
I made it public here: http://unf.yiedl.io.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ I see the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: BrowserSolc is not defined" in console when accessing it from FF and Chrome (Ubuntu).

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This code does not produce an error for me. Are you doing anything else?

Comment: @kabanus I made it public here: http://unf.yiedl.io.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ I see the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: BrowserSolc is not defined" in console when accessing it from FF and Chrome (Ubuntu). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an issue related to your question in repo
https://github.com/ericxtang/browser-solc/issues/1

Comment: Ty! Do you think there is any workaround? How difficult it would be to fix it? I'm quite new to JS.

Comment: if you own the page where you want to add this library, you should just use <script> tag. If not, you cannot do it probably. 
But browser-solc seems old (updated last 2 years ago). Just grab the code from http://code.dappbench.com/browser-solc.min.js and use it.
Don't forget the ISC license if you  will release something important :)